# How to prevent img src 404 error when unit testing using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, image, unit-testing, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I'm running Jasmine tests with Karma under PhantomJS.
I have a test that checks that the `src` attribute of an `<img/>` is set correctly.
PhantomJS rightly warns about a 404 error trying to retrieve a non-existent file, since the `src` is set to the string value of `"imgSrc"`.

The test is `expect(imageElement.getAttribute('src')).toBe("imgSrc");`.

How can I silent 404 image src wranings, preferablly on a test-to-test basis?

Note that specifying an image URL that exists is not something I am considering.
I want to test that a function sets the image src to a passed-in value, don't care if that value exists for the purpose of this unit test.

Comment: I don't, it's PhantomJS normal logging of HTTP error codes.

Comment: Log level is set to `config.LOG_INFO`. Not sure I understand your question, Arjom.

Comment: The warning is thrown in the console output.

Comment: Sorry about that. The warning shows in the terminal when running unit tests with Karma under PhantomJS.

Comment: I've made edits to the question.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using **karma** framework for example, ensure to serve statically images referenced in `src="..."` attributes.

Comment: There is no image referenced intentionally. I'm not testing the `<img/>` tag.

Comment: Could you be more precise regarding to this filename?

Comment: I what sense? The filename is a string which does not map to a resource on the server.